# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN select best match without changing sql_mode

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I'm trying to get a list of students with their best matching subject from subject_inv table. The issue with my query is it requires to change sql_mode. Is there a way to modify this query without changing sql_mode parameter.

```
    SELECT `student`.*, `subject_inv`.`subject_name`, `score`.`custom_score`, 
    MIN(
    CASE WHEN (`student`.`subject` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 1 WHEN (`student`.`topic1` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 2 WHEN (`student`.`topic2` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 3 WHEN (`student`.`topic3` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 4 END
    ) AS priority 
    FROM `student` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `subject_inv` ON `subject_inv`.`subject_name`=`student`.`subject` OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic1` OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic2` OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic3` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `score` ON `student`.`id`=`score`.`id` GROUP BY `student`.`id`, priority
```

It gives me following error. Probably it should fix when I change the sql_mode from "only_full_group_by" to other.

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.student.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Is there a way to get this result without changing sql_mode ?

```
student
id | full_name | subject | topic1 | topic2 | topic3
___________________________________________________
1  | tom       | sbj1    | sbj4   |        |
2  | sam       | sbj3    | sbj7   |        |
3  | ron       | sbj6    | sbj2   |        |    

subject_inv
id | subject_name | tutor
__________________________
1  | sbj1         | tut1
2  | sbj7         | tut2
3  | sbj4         | tut3
4  | sbj9         | tut3

score
id | custom_score
__________________
1  | 10         
2  | 6         
3  | 9         
4  | 4
```

expected results:::

```
id | full_name | subject | topic1 | topic2 | topic3 | subject_name | custom_score
________________________________________________________________________________
1  | tom       | sbj1    | sbj4   |        |        | sbj1         | 10
2  | sam       | sbj3    | sbj7   |        |        | sbj7         | 6
3  | ron       | sbj6    | sbj2   |        |        | NULL         | 9
```

Comment: What sql_modes are you reffering to?

Comment: It gives me following error. probably it should fix when I change the sql_mode from "only_full_group_by" to other.

#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.student.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be really helpful.

Comment: I have added sample structure/data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be interested to know how this query performs (and if it produces the expected result) , using coalesce to prioritise. Note I have renamed the tables.

```
drop table if exists st,su,sc;
create table st(id int, full_name varchar(20), subject varchar(20), topic1 varchar(20), topic2 varchar(20), topic3 varchar(20));
insert into st values
(1  , 'tom'       , 'sbj1'    , 'sbj4'   , null,null),
(2  , 'sam'       , 'sbj3'    , 'sbj7'   , null,null),       
(3  , 'ron'       , 'sbj6'    , 'sbj2'   , null,null);

create table su(id int, subject_name varchar(20), tutor varchar(20));
insert into su values
(1  , 'sbj1'         , 'tut1'),
(2  , 'sbj7'         , 'tut2'),
(3  , 'sbj4'         , 'tut3'),
(4  , 'sbj9'         , 'tut3');

create table sc(id int, custom_score int);
insert into sc values
(1  , 10),         
(2  , 6  ),       
(3  , 9  ),       
(4  , 4);

select  st.id,st.full_name,st.subject,st.topic1,st.topic2,st.topic3,
        coalesce((select su.subject_name from su where su.subject_name = st.subject) ,
                (select su.subject_name from su where su.subject_name = st.topic1) ,
                (select su.subject_name from su where su.subject_name = st.topic2) ,
                (select su.subject_name from su where su.subject_name = st.topic3)
                )  subjectname,
         custom_score
from st
left join sc on sc.id = st.id;

+------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
| id   | full_name | subject | topic1 | topic2 | topic3 | subjectname | custom_score |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|    1 | tom       | sbj1    | sbj4   | NULL   | NULL   | sbj1        |           10 |
|    2 | sam       | sbj3    | sbj7   | NULL   | NULL   | sbj7        |            6 |
|    3 | ron       | sbj6    | sbj2   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL        |            9 |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Performed very well, Earlier it was 0.1 sec and with this query it is just 0.005 sec

Answer (score 1):

you could use a inner join with the subselect for MIN eg:

```
 SELECT distinct  `student`.*, `subject_inv`.`subject_name`, `score`.`custom_score`
 , t.priority 
  FROM `student` 
  INNER JOIN (

    select  `student`.`id`, MIN(
        CASE  WHEN (`student`.`subject` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 1 
              WHEN (`student`.`topic1` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 2 
              WHEN (`student`.`topic2` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 3 
              WHEN (`student`.`topic3` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 4 END
        ) AS priority 
        FROM `student`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `subject_inv` ON `subject_inv`.`subject_name`=`student`.`subject` 
            OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic1` 
              OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic2` 
                OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic3`
    group by `student`.`id`
  ) t on t.`id` = `student`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `subject_inv` ON `subject_inv`.`subject_name`=`student`.`subject` 
      OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic1` 
        OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic2` 
          OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic3` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `score` ON `student`.`id`=`score`.`id`
```

but for sql_mode=only_full_group_by
if you need  outhers column that a not in group by you should use aggreagtion function too

```
 SELECT  `student`.*
 , min(`subject_inv`.`subject_name`)
 , min(`score`.`custom_score`)
 , t.priority 
  FROM `student` 
  INNER JOIN (

    select  `student`.`id`, MIN(
        CASE  WHEN (`student`.`subject` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 1 
              WHEN (`student`.`topic1` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 2 
              WHEN (`student`.`topic2` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 3 
              WHEN (`student`.`topic3` = `subject_inv`.`subject_name`) THEN 4 END
        ) AS priority 
        FROM `student`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `subject_inv` ON `subject_inv`.`subject_name`=`student`.`subject` 
            OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic1` 
              OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic2` 
                OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic3`
    group by `student`.`id`
  ) t on t.`id` = `student`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `subject_inv` ON `subject_inv`.`subject_name`=`student`.`subject` 
      OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic1` 
        OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic2` 
          OR `subject_inv`.`subject_name` = `student`.`topic3` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `score` ON `student`.`id`=`score`.`id` 
  GROUP BY `student`.`id`, t.priority
```

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: answer  updated .. there is not the group with the joined  subquery ,..

Comment: then it returns duplicates. I need only best matches.

Comment: answer updated.. with distinct  .. but you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. seems that your problem si not simply related  to the group by sql_mode ..

Comment: still returns duplicates. okay, let me add sample db structure and data.

Comment: i have added  a suggestion for avoid duplicates .. hope is useful

Comment: it seems working fine, When I changed 

, min(`subject_inv`.`subject_name`)
 , min(`score`.`custom_score`)

to 

, max(`subject_inv`.`subject_name`)

Comment: Is there a way to optimize this query using query ranking method ?

Comment: This query takes a long time time to execute. Is there any other way to optimize this query. maybe grouped ranking method instead of using case ?

Comment: for preformance you must check  for index .. you should add  (if you have not)  proper composite index  for the column involved  in join ,, but you  have several OR clause that reduce drastically the performance  ..(expecially check for  indexes over student.topic1,  2,,,3  ..anyway this seems another question to me

Comment: I have added sample structure/data

Comment: for better performance you should avoid  the .topic1, 2,,,3 . as 3 columns and normalize these data in proper table  .. anyway  ..for a proper eval of indexes  you should post a new question  and not extend this one ..  do the fact your original question is already solved  ..  in the new question you should explain your question and add  also  the tables schema  (indexes  included)   ... not only the columns name and data sample  ..